# ¿Como guardo los parámetros de una url en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Quisiera guardar los parámetros de una url. Por ejemplo:

`#/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=1&Corte=50`.

Como puedo hacer para guardarlo y cuando haga clic en un botón me lo devuelva en la barra de direcciones, lo quiero usar para crear un botón que me vuelva a los resultados de mi busqueda, ya que con el `history.go(-1)` tengo un problema y es que al actualizar los datos de mi búsqueda me vuelve a mi formulario y quiero omitir eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi esta pregunta. lo que hice fue hacer esto:

1- Agrege esto en el controller al final del código de mi consulta

```
    var URLactual = window.location.href;
sessionStorage.setItem('Volver', URLactual)
```

Lo que hace es guardar la url completa con los parametros de busqueda en la sessionStorange.

2- Agregar esto en el controller de mi vista donde estara el boton volver:

```
    this.Volver = function () {
    location.href = sessionStorage.Volver
}
```

Aqui devuelve el valor de la URL

3- en la vista donde estara el boton volver agrege los siguiente:

```
<button role="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" ng-click="detalle.Volver()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i> Volver</button>
```

Comment: Esto es una mala idea porque es como usar una caja para guardar una caja. La query del navegador puede usarse como almacenamiento ya que permite serializar y deserializar información. Lo que debes hacer es preservar los parametros de la query pasandolos al próximo controller, de esta forma si se actualiza la página la información no se pierde. Tu solución asume que el usuario va a abrir las páginas en el orden que quieres lo cual siempre conduce a mala arquitectura.

Answer (score 1):

En angular puedes usar [`$location.search()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) para obtener los parámetros de la query.

Este método es getter/setter lo que quiere decir que para la url

```
#/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=1&Corte=50
```

al invocarlo como getter

```
$location.search() => {Cedula: 170259, Pagina: 1, Corte: 50}
```

Si lo usas como setter la sintáxis puede variar

1. Si el primer parámetro no es un string o un número

   ```
   // Objeto
   $location.search({Cedula: 170259, Pagina: 2, Corte: 60})
   // resultado
   // serializar el objeto en la query
   #/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=2&Corte=60


   // Objeto con un arreglo de string
   $location.search({Cedula: ['170259', '170260', '170261']})
   // resultado
   // se duplican los parámetros de la query
   #/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Cedula=170260&Cedula=170261
   ```
2. Si el primer parámetro es un string o número

   ```
   // Usando null
   $location.search('Pagina', null)
   // resultado
   // Se elimina un sólo parámetro
   #/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Corte=50

   // Usando true
   $location.search('Corte', true)
   // resultado
   // Se agrega el parámetro sin valor y signo igual
   #/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=1&Corte

   // Usando un arreglo
   $location.search('Pagina', [1, 2, 3]);
   // resultado
   // Se sobreescribe el parámetro varias veces
   #/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=1&Pagina=2&Pagina=3&Corte=50
   ```

Aquí tienes un demo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('reset', function($location) {
    return function() {
      console.log($location.url());
      $location.url('/registro/licencia/consultar?Cedula=170259&Pagina=1&Corte=50');
    }
  })
  .run(function(reset) {
    reset();
  })
  .controller('LocationCtrl', function($location, reset) {

    console.log('--- Getter ---');
    console.log($location.search());

    console.log('--- Setter ---');
    $location.search({
      Cedula: 170259,
      Pagina: 2,
      Corte: 60
    });
    reset();

    $location.search({
      Cedula: ['170259', '170260', '170261']
    });
    reset();

    $location.search('Pagina', null);
    reset();

    $location.search('Corte', true);
    reset();

    $location.search('Pagina', [1, 2, 3]);
    reset();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="LocationCtrl"></div>
```

Una vez que lo obtienes puedes guardarlo donde desees. Yo te recomendaría que usases el mismo servicio `$location` para manipular los valores en la misma query(usarla como tu storage) y así si el usuario refresca la página estos no se pierden.

Como mejor alternativa puedes usar una solución de routing completa como [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) o [`ui-router`](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/).

Comment: vale, voy entendiendo, pero pasa que la url varia de acuerdo a la busqueda, y mas parametros se agregan dependiendo de lo que se escriba. tambien puede tener nombre, apellido, nro de computacion. lo que quiero es que guarde y devuelva sin importar lo que haya em la url, varie o no el numero o se le agregue mas parametros. soy nuevo en el tema de Angular asi que entiendo muy poco

Comment: @SebastianKullman Te recomiendo que uses un framework de ruteo como los mencionados, preferiblemente `ui-router` que es basado en estados. Para hacer una nueva búsqueda solo tienes que navegar hacia el mismo estado con parámetros diferentes no tienes que estar lidiando con la url y el historial tu mismo. En el controller de la página de búsqueda pones la lógica y la llamada a ajax para obtener los resultados. Recuerda que angular es un [SPA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), consulta *Historial del Navegador*. cuando diseñes aplicaciones debes tener esas cosas presentes.